# Настройка rsync

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, rsync

Всем привет. Может ли кто то подсказать по поводу настройки rsync. Не смог найти инфы. Что есть:
В офисе стоит микротик и nas synology
Нужно бэкапить ВМ
На одной из ВМ решил попробовать rsync.
На микротике сделан проброс портов, адрес synology xxx.xx.xx.x:5000
Из внешки доступ есть
В Synology rsync включен, учетка добавлена, доступы предоставлены
При попытке архивировать хоть что то, rsync пытается подключится, видимо, к адресу ххх.хх.хх.х без порта по ssh и выдает ошибку

`sudo rsync -avnzx /home/Backupvm@xxx.xx.xx.x:5000:/volume1/NetBackup/ ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.x port 22: Connection timed out rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]`

На микротике открывать порт не хочется
Менять порты на ВМ не вариант
Как то можно настроить чтобы он подключался по 5000 порту без ssh, или какой то другой вариант?
Не бейте палками, я новокек

Comment: Так ты по rsync хочешь лить или по ssh?

Comment: Гляньте в маны. Там, во-первых, написано, как указать порт, а во-вторых, целая глава про то, как коннектиться именно к rsyncd, а не к ssh. У вас слишком много разного написано, чтобы понять, каким конкретно методом вы пытаетесь подключиться.